# what about using a static class with static properties returning new instances of concrete classes extending an abstract one

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, static, instance

MyObject has a shape and the shape have to be chosen and passed as argument to the ctor, can't exist a MyObject whitout a shape and the shape can't vary along his life. It happens often in real life.

```
namespace JackNova.ConsoleClient.Test.Fun
{
abstract class Shape { }

class Circle : Shape { }
class Square : Shape { }
class Triangle : Shape { }

static class Shapes
{
    public static Circle Circle { get { return new Circle(); } }
    public static Square Square { get { return new Square(); } }
    public static Triangle Triangle { get { return new Triangle(); } }
}

class MyObject
{
    public Shape Shape { get; private set; }

    public MyObject(Shape shape)
    {
        this.Shape = shape;
    }

}

class Test
{
    static void Run()
    {
        MyObject coolOne = new MyObject(Shapes.Circle);
    }
}
}
```

I think I'm violating some principle here, the open closed one for example.
My purpose is to simplify developing at design time. As you can see when I instanciate MyObject I don't have to remeber wich kind of objects I can pass as argument but they are instanciated and passed by the abstract class.

Do you think this sucks?

Comment: it is interesting how .net framework does similar things just using enums: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to have an abstract class and a class which takes a reference to an instance of that abstract class in the constructor and sets an effectively-readonly property.

I would question your use of properties in the static class though:

- How do you benefit in usage over just calling `new Circle()`?
- If there *were* a benefit, I think it would still make sense to make these methods instead of properties.

Comment: just needed something "similar to enumerable" but I don't need the enumerator... the sole purpose is in design time, nothing different for calling new Circle(), but calling new Circle() means you know wich classes extends the abstract base, my Shapes class only serves as a "container" for classes you can pass.

Comment: @JackNova: Well, if you're using `Shapes.Circle` you know you're getting a `Circle` too... but you could certainly have a `Shapes.NewCircle()` method instead.

Comment: what about properties named with New prefix?

Comment: @JackNova: I wouldn't. It's slightly odd for a property to create a new instance every time, even with the `New` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are trying to do should be a function of the tool. For example, Visual Studio's IntelliSense would tell you the valid types that can be passed into MyObject.

Also, properties should generally not have any side-effects. So the Circle property should really be a CreateCircle method (or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it violates a principle, but I really like the readability and expressivity of this syntax.

If you consider that shapes are [value objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ValueObject), does it matter that much that each call to Shapes.Circle creates a new Circle ?